# Can a PC be forced to convert to another deity by a ranking priest/priestess and holy symbol?

Tags: adnd-2e, religions-and-deities

Here's a situation; Our game world allows for traditionally non PC monsters to be PC (i.e. Orcs, Goblins, Illithid, Ogres). At one point a monster character I was playing became temporarily paralyzed. During that paralization a priestess put her holy symbol on me, and attempted a forced conversion. I was allowed 3 checks against my wisdom as a save (I had to roll above) and failed to "save" twice and was automatically converted. There is a slight alignment conflict but not outside the realm of possibility. My concern is that my character was at one time not aligned with any particular deity and now I'm assumed to be a follower.

To be truthful I am looking for a way out of it, but are there any particular rules against forced conversions?

Comment: If, for example, the answer to "are there any particular rules agains forced conversions" is *no,* what further help are you looking for?  Is there a personal problem between you and the DM, or a communication problem, that will influence how anyone can answer this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This unfortunately isn't a rules issue. You should talk to your DM directly if you feel your character agency is being infringed on. AD&D doesn't explicitly define the rules relating to forcing a player to change alignment or deities, but you could reasonably argue that the advice in the DMG implies that deity choice and alignment are core character concepts (Page 25, changing alignment) and that such a change would make your character unplayable in strict RAW. I wouldn't approach it from this angle initially as your DM is free to implement any rules they choose, but you could use this to argue that your agency of choice when it comes to your permanent alignment and deity choice is privileged in the design intent of the system.

Answer (score 5):

### Yes, there are rules for magical forced changes in alignment

However, in AD&D 2e, RAW isn't the core philosophy of the game.

#### First, the rule

In the DMG, there is a brief treatment of alignment change via magical means.

> **Magical Alignment Changes**
>   A second, more insidious, type of magical item is the one that changes a character's alignment.  Unlike the usual, gradual methods by which a character changes alignment, magical alignment changes are instantaneous.  The character's personality undergoes an immediate transformation, something like magical brainwashing.  Depending on the new alignment, the change may or may not be immediately noticeable.
>   {And then it says ...}
>   However, you should insist that the player role-play his new situation. Do not allow him to ignore the effects the alignment change will have on his character's personality.  Indeed, good role-players will take this as an opportunity to stretch their skills.

What happened to you fits within this DMG guidance.  (The holy symbol could very well be a strong enough magical item that it can do as cursed items or artifacts can do ... that's within the DM's realm of world creation).  As you did not state how many are in your group, it is hard to see how good or bad this change will be for the group as a whole, though from your question it's got some downside.

#### More DMG Guidance, and 2e philosophy is *rules are guidelines*

The AD&D 2e DMG advises in the Foreward that the books don't contain all rules for all situations.  Even though the case you describe fits this general guidance to GM's, the DMG also suggests *that the DM listen to your feedback.*

> **Dealing with Dissatisfied Players**
>   All of the above notwithstanding, you don't want to force a player to accept a character he doesn't really like. All you will do is lose a player. If someone really is dissatisfied, either make some adjustments to the character or let him
>   roll up a new one.

While that passage was related to rolling up characters, the principle applies to a lot of situations with unhappy players.  As I don't know what the interpersonal dynamics are at your table, what may be happening is that *your DM is presenting you with a role-playing challenge*.

- Are you up for it?  One way to approach this is "life dealt me
  lemons, I'm going to make lemonade."
- Are you not up for it?  You missed a saving throw and a deity has claimed you has his/hers.  If you want to fight it (stories about mere mortals thwarting the will of deities abound -- Elric of Melnibone comes to mind), you need to work with your DM on how your character can begin the struggle back to his original status.  I'll address a few points on that further down.

#### DMG Suggests that DM's work things out

Dave "Zeb" Cook(DMG author) provides this advice to GM's in the Foreward:

> Don't just let the game sit there, and don't become a rules lawyer worrying about each piddly little detail. If you can't figure out the answer, MAKE IT UP!  And whatever you do, don't fall into the trap of believing these rules are complete.  They are not.  You cannot sit back and let the rule book do everything for you. {snip}  I'm often asked for the instant answer to a fine point of the game rules.  More often than not, I come back with a question — what do you feel is right?  And the people asking the questions discover that not only can they create an answer, but that their answer is as good as anyone else's. **The rules are only guidelines.** {snip} As a Dungeon Master, you have great power, and "with great power comes great responsibility." Use it wisely.

OK, that's advice for the DM, what about you, the player?

#### Talk to your DM and *find out if this is meant as a role playing challenge*.

While the rules are on his side, there are other considerations:

- There may be an overarching campaign reason behind this problem
- You may or may not perceive the challenge to role playing a differently aligned character as fun.  If that is the case, the DM needs to know that from you, in person.

If you'd rather not try play the character with this significant change, (your call) then you need to have a conversation with the DM.  Two core points will arise in that discussion. (preferably outside of game time, before the next session).

1. Do I roll up another character?  (That is one choice you have).
2. Is there a way that the party and I can overcome this bad outcome due to my bad luck / failed saving throws?  (And later on, sweet revenge against that priestess and her temple, eh?)

The second point is a way to get a quest / adventure that becomes very personal, and in some ways enriching.  That will depend upon how it's handled by both the DM and the Party.  As above, this event may be a part of the campaign that you all have not yet encountered.)  It's very much up to the group how much fun this quest might be (or how much fun it won't be).

#### Bottom Line

Technically, the rules support this being a valid outcome.  Given two chances to a save being failed (like missing two chances to save versus being turned into stone by a spell, but much more dire) you (and the rest of the party) play on from there.

The DMG also calls on the DM to listen to player feedback.

#### Courses of Action for you to choose from

Talk to your DM, and the group as appropriate, and arrive at a consensus:

1. Its' a role playing challenge, you will take it on.
2. It's a set back for you and the party, you want to find a path / quest / adventure with the purpose of undoing this.
3. You don't want to play that character with a new god/alignment.
   a. You can roll up a new character (this one can become an NPC)
   b. You can choose not to play.
   c. Other options that arise during conversation.

   3.b will hopefully not arise.  That said, if you feel that you are being railroaded, and that this just isn't fun for you, and the DM won't work with you on this, it is *a choice*.

We play the game for fun.   Best wishes, however it works out.